# Auto build on Github

Tags: reactjs, github

I'm new to using React and I have a little problem. I would like to host a React project on Github and make that when one of the collaborators modifies the code of a JS or HTML or CSS page, this modification is also carried out in the build or perhaps after launching a script. How should I do it ?
But if you have another solution to offer me so that we can work together on the same React project, I'm interested.
Thank you in advance

Comment: This is trivial with GitHub Pages and GitHub Actions, here's one repo I set up: https://github.com/textbook/abv.

Comment: Tank you, but can you create a empty React repo because yours is without JS file and with other that I don't know their utility. Thanks

Comment: No, I'm not creating it for you, but that gives you a _starting point_ to research and build your own.